# John the ripper 0 password hashes cracked, 38 left

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

Kali linux latest build trying to use John the Ripper

I have the hashes in a file called `userhash.txt`

So I try this: (just starting to see if it works)

```
john --wordlist=word.lst userhash.txt 
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Using default target encoding: CP850
Loaded 38 password hashes with no different salts (LM [DES 128/128 AVX-16])
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2019-01-24 22:27) 0g/s 2917Kp/s 2917Kc/s 110860KC/s VZHBR..VJHT008
Session completed
```

then if I do a `--show` I get  `0 password hashes cracked, 38 left`
Any ideas?

Comment: Never used `john` myself, but it looks to me like it's saying it went through the whole word list and didn't manage to crack any of the passwords.

Comment: That's what it looks like to me, too. The passwords couldn't be cracked given the wordlist provided
.

Comment: I recommend you verify your understanding of the tool by creating a hash for a weak password (something in the wordlist you're using) and adding it to the userhash.txt file, and then verifying that `john` cracks that one.

Comment: Havent checked what are the ones implemented in Kali, but you have different types of password related tools. a) Dictionary tools (normal or rainbow tables) b) Bruteforce tools. If you are using dictionary ones, maybe it is not in the dictionary. Do note that brute forcing with complex and long passwords could be impossible (too much time)

Comment: I tried creating a hash on one of those websites then put it into a file. Tried John with a sample wordlist I created (with the password in it) and it worked. Took seconds. So my understanding of the tool and seeing it work is getting better.  Original file with hashes was derived from DSinternals: Dumping the contents of ntds.dit files using PowerShell. When I run this hashes.txt file with John and a wordlist it just finishes in seconds. no passwords cracked. If i run it alone ./john hashes.txt it takes days and no results.

Comment: ... the length of time will depend on how long the wordlist is ... if you don't specify a wordlist, then it will try every character combination in existence... I really think you need to look up how the tools works in its different modes.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is a one-way process that transforms a password into a fixed-length string of characters. You cannot simply reverse to its original value, just by the information provided by the hash.

[image: Hash function explained] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#/media/File:Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg)

<sub>The image also shows a collision(=Multiple values have the same hash) which can be ignored for answering your question</sub>

In order to get the plaintext, you need to find a string that, when hashed using the same algorithm, matches the stored hash. In your case the dictionary.

When John the Ripper returns "Session completed," it means that it has gone through the entire wordlist you provided without successfully cracking any of the hashes. It only indicates John has exhausted its attempts with the given wordlist and hasn't found matching passwords (inside the dict) for the hashes.